# How to set multiple https listeners on same AWS ALB without passing in port?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I’ve got multiple applications I’m needing to deploy via ecs fargate using an application load balancer. The applications have separate dns records associated with them and each has their own certs of course to be attached to the ALB.

This is where things get interesting. If I deploy one of the applications on a 443 listener this works. However when I go to deploy the other set of apps on a separate https listener (since you can’t have duplicate 443 listeners) this time on 44301, I can only reach the app by passing in 44301 to the url with the route path. In other words in the first case, 443 is the default and I don’t have to pass that port in when I hit the url, but in the second case, I do have to pass in the port.

Is it possible to have the second https listener default to that other https port without having to pass in that port number?

I’m using separate https listeners to save cost and so I don’t have to create a separate alb for each dns record.

So far I haven’t tried to add a redirect rule to that port, but I’ve tried the other deployment strategies listed above and I can’t get the second https listener to work with the cert without also passing in that port to the url.

Comment: Sadly you can't do that. Listeners require ports, and you can't create one without port.

Comment: I still dont get why you have multiple ports. ALB supports multiple TLS certficates. you can use port 443 and host based or path routing to redirect to appropriate ECS service.

Comment: If there’s a simpler way I’m all ears. I’ve got two separate certs for separate dns records. Some of the apps have the same base route path which is why I was assuming I would need to use separate listeners for each as there would be duplicate paths if I didn’t on the same listener. If the service is in a separate ecs cluster but the task definition and target group is different could that work if I added the certs and then added the extra target group to the same route path? That is I think I can add multiple target groups to the same path.

Comment: Note: also due to environment limitations I’m unable to use acm for the certs. These are issued by a CA and then uploaded and set from IAM.

Comment: What's stopping you from uploading the cert to ACM instead of IAM?

Comment: In the environment we’re using we don’t and can’t get  permissions to use acm